# how to reference parent javascript function from ts module?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-analytics

I need to call a js function in the parent page of a ts module. I can use the jQuery context on the parent page from a ts module by using code like this:

```
var x = (<any>$('#ddlUsers'))
```

I have another scenario where I'm isolating some Google Analytics logic into a ts module and I need to call the following function:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Google Analytics has some standard script configuration before the end head tag in the parent page.  The ga() function above is the standard way in GA to send an event. So how can I make this call from a ts module?

Comment: How about `(ga as any)('send', 'pageview');`?

Comment: That approach returns an error of: "Cannot find name 'ga'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare ga at the top of your ts module

```
declare const ga;
```

now you can use it throughout your module

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: thanks LLai.  this compiles now.  hopefully this works as expected at runtime when dev is complete :)